# Can't bind a resized image (as a blob) to my form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an image upload interface, but to do the resizing on the client side so as to not tax my server (original files are generally 4Mb each, and I need files that are ~300kb)

I have my `<input type="file" name="image0" />`, and select my file ("cat.gif").

I then resize it, following the recipe at [Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/). I'm left with a blob which I try to put back into my form:

```
//should I be trying to set the FormData in the presently-blank callback function?
var blob = canvas.toBlob(function(){}, "image/png", 0.95); 
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var fd = new FormData(form);
fd.set("image0", blob);
```

When I submit the form, it sends the original image file ("cat.gif") I inputed, not the modified one I made as a blob. Here's part of the POST payload:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image0"; filename="cat.gif"`

How do I bind the blob to the form input?

Comment: `var fd = new FormData(); fd.append('image0', blob)` <- stop adding the entire form to the formdata

Comment: you shouldn't be submitting a <form> if you use FormData, just ajax it (you already duped the <form> anyway, so it should be ready to go)

Comment: But is it even possible to resize an image client side and then submit it synchronously as part of a form then? (I should specify that `image0` is not the only field in my form).

Comment: @Escher: no, not really. you could use a hidden/text input and dataURL, but not for something 4mb in size... i think i saw vauge talk somewhere about a proposal for a way of constructing populated file inputs, but that's not anywhere in the wild afaik...

Comment: ... unless you send the form with ajax

Comment: See [Chrome: Create file input from blob with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739946/chrome-create-file-input-from-blob-with-javascript)

Comment: @dandavis _"i think i saw vauge talk somewhere about a proposal for a way of constructing populated file inputs, but that's not anywhere in the wild afaik... "_ `new File()` constructor is available in chromium / chrome 38+ https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5731244088229888

Comment: @guest271314: that is probably what i saw, it was about 6 months ago. thanks for the link. but looking at that, i now realize it's only half the battle for the OP; there's still no way to pop the <input> to "spoof" a file submit on a "real" <form>...

Comment: @dandavis You are correct about "spoof"ing `input` `Files` object; could send created `Blob` , `File` object or `data URI`, as suggested. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365796/simulate-drop-file-event/

Comment: @Escher See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289488/blob-url-to-file-with-php

Comment: @Escher What is server side language ?

Comment: Python/Django. The short answer to this question is "you can't do it that way", and so I've moved on to ajax here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805257/how-to-post-and-retrieve-blob-with-django