# How to post and retrieve blob with Django

Tags: python, django, blob

I have a `blob`. It's an image that I resized using a `<canvas>`. I've verified that the data is correct by converting it to a url to test it as per [the MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). So far so good. Now, I'd like to post it to my Django server (along with some other inputs).

So I do this:

```
var fd = new FormData(form);
canvas.toBlob( function(blob) {
  fd.set("image0", blob, "image0.jpg");
}, "image/jpeg", 0.7);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/ajax-upload/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
xhr.send(fd);
```

I inspect the POST message with the network inspector console. My blob is confirmed as sent with the POST request and I can see the binary data send as the "image0" field.

```
-----------------------------1773139883502878911993383390
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image0"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png
```

So I handle the POST request with this view, accessible at url `/ajax-upload/`:

```
def ajax_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.urlencode())
```

This gives me nothing. Once I find out where my blob went, how can I turn it into an `Image`? Something like `img = Image.open(request.POST["image0"])`?

Comment: what is returned in request.FILES?

Comment: request.FILES appears to be empty: `<MultiValueDict: {}>`

Answer (score 3):

A blob is binary data, so you can find it in the `request.body` in Django. Its `Bytes` encoded (not Unicode).

> [HttpRequest.body](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)
> The raw HTTP request body as a bytestring. This is useful for processing data in different ways than conventional HTML forms: binary images, XML payload etc.

Comment: Please link your source.

Comment: @J F - Click the link at `HttpRequest.body` and I think you'll find @C14L has already done what you asked for.

Comment: `request.body` is inaccessible if you have a bunch of middleware in Django.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy, you may just... read it:

```
#views.py
from django.views import View

class Upload(View):

    def get(self, request):     
        # Sanity check if your server is up and running, reply to GET HTTP requests
        print('Got get request...') # log it for the debug purpose
        return HttpResponse('<H1>It is GET request, use POST</H1>', status=200)        

    def post(self, request):
        # Here, I'm using it with plupload.js for the chunked upload, but it would work anyway
        ... ## here, you'd do something with the headers
        file_name = request.POST['name'] # or some constant 'file_name_with_path.bin'
        chunk_num = int(request.POST['chunk']) # get it from the request 
        
        ## Finally, you know this is multipart-type, and headers are okay, let store it! 
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file'] # data from the request
        if chunk_num == 0: 
            ## The very first chunk — create/overwrite a binary file
            with open(file_name, 'wb+') as f:
                f.write(uploaded_file.read()) # <—— so, just read it from the request!
        else:
            ## Next chunks — append to the file!
            with open(file_name, 'ab') as f:
                f.write(uploaded_file.read())
```

In your case:

```
def ajax_upload(request):
    ...
    img = Image.open(request.POST["file"].read())
    ...
    return HttpResponse('{"Status":"OK"}', status=200)
```

Nota Bene: I am aware, that the question is a bit old, but I had the same issue and solved it in no time, but I struggled trying to find a solution by searching initially...