# Save image blob url in php

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller i receive a image url in blob

https://adonai.eduxenet.com.br/290beb51-094f-4f6a-bd9f-a37cf49d1c25" >

I've tried in several ways to get the image and I can not

how can I get this image and save it to my server?

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $detail=$request->layoutDocumento;
    debug_var($detail);


    $dom = new \domdocument();
    @$dom->loadHtml(utf8_decode($detail), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $images = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');


    foreach($images as $k => $img){
        $data = $img->getattribute('src');

        //list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        //list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

        //$data = base64_encode($data);


        $uploadArquivo = $this->salvaDocumento(\Session::get('app.cliente_id'),
                                           \Session::get('id_unidade_selecionada'),
                                            $request->id_categoria ,
                                            $request->id_documento ,
                                            $blob);

        debug_var($uploadArquivo);

        $imagem_url = \Config::get('app.storage') . '/' . $uploadArquivo;
        $img->removeattribute('src');
        $img->setattribute('src', $imagem_url);
    }


    $detail = $dom->savehtml();


    $documento = new Documento;
    $documento->id_tipo_documentos = $request->id_documento;
    $documento->st_vingente = '1';
    $documento->st_matricula = '1';
    $documento->tp_layout = 'portrait';
    $documento->layout = $detail;
    $documento->save();
    \Session::forget('msg_documentos');
    \Session::put('msg_documentos', "Documento salvo com sucesso !");
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Comment: How is the data being passed?

Comment: is a HTML editor i want store the images content inside

Comment: i receive <img alt="" src="blob:https://mydomain/290beb51-094f-4f6a-bd9f-a37cf49d1c25" width="270">

Comment: OK, can you show me your route and controller code in the question please?

Comment: i receive a normal html <figure class="easyimage easyimage-full"><img alt="" src="blob:https://mydomain/290beb51-094f-4f6a-bd9f-a37cf49d1c25" width="270">
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>

Comment: but i want to save in other cloud this is my problem

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289488/blob-url-to-file-with-php